# Slice and iter() simultaneously

Tags: rust

I am trying to figure out why this does not work ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=15f67014fa6badd1a99183b620d82b36&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let b = a.clone();
    // slice and iter (wrong way)
    let s: i32 = &a[1..a.len()].iter()
        .zip(&b[1..b.len()].iter())
        .map(|(x, y)| x * y)
        .sum();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Error:

```
rustc 1.13.0 (2c6933acc 2016-11-07)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
 --> <anon>:6:10
  |
6 |         .zip(&b[1..b.len()].iter())
  |          ^^^ trait `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>: std::iter::Iterator` not satisfied
  |
  = note: `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>`

error: no method named `map` found for type `std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, &std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>>` in the current scope
 --> <anon>:7:10
  |
7 |         .map(|(x, y)| x * y)
  |          ^^^
  |
  = note: the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied: `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}> : std::iter::Iterator`, `std::iter::Zip<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, &std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

But this does work:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let b = a.clone();
    // slice and iter (correct way)
    let s: i32 = a[1..a.len()].iter()
        .zip(b[1..b.len()].iter())
        .map(|(x, y)| x * y)
        .sum();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Please explain how vectors work in Rust and the difference above when I `iter()`.

Comment: Not really fluent in Rust, but I'm pretty sure it has to do with using a reference to `a` and `b` that cause the problem. What you really want is use the object directly as in the "working code".

Comment: would enjoy if the answer could address what the borrow applies to in `&a[1..a.len()].iter().zip(&b[1..b.len()].iter()).map(|(x, y)| x*y).sum()` is it the same as `&(a[1..a.len()]).iter().zip(&(b[1..b.len()]).iter()).map(|(x, y)| x*y).sum()` or `&(a[1..a.len()].iter().zip(&(b[1..b.len()].iter())).map(|(x, y)| x*y).sum())`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In short**: you probably misunderstood operator precedence:

```
&b[1..b.len()].iter()
```

Is equal to:

```
&(b[1..b.len()].iter())
```

And since `zip()` is expecting something that implements `IntoIterator`, the call fails, since a reference to this iterator type does not implement said trait.

---

### Full Explanation

Let's try to understand the error message! Of course, we will first just look at the first error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>: std::iter::Iterator` is not satisfied
 --> <anon>:6:10
  |
6 |         .zip(&b[1..b.len()].iter())
  |          ^^^ trait `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>: std::iter::Iterator` not satisfied
  |
  = note: `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>` is not an iterator; maybe try calling `.iter()` or a similar method
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>`
```

Wow, that's quite a mouthful. But we can see that some trait bound requirement of the [function `zip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) is violated. So, let's look at the signature of said function:

```
fn zip<U>(self, other: U) -> Zip<Self, U::IntoIter> 
    where U: IntoIterator
```

What matters is the `other` argument (type `U`). `U` has to be [`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html). This trait is implemented for quite a few types ... let's check what type we're trying to pass into `zip()`:

```
&b[1..b.len()].iter()
```

To analyze this completely, we need to understand quite something, but I'll try to break it down. First, let's disambiguate operator precedence by inserting more parenthesis. The above code snippet is equivalent to:

```
&(b[1..b.len()].iter())
```

1. An expression `foo[bar]` desugares to `*::std::ops::Index::index(&foo, bar)`. This is the most complex part here, but looking this up in the documentation reveals that the expression `b[1..b.len()]` has the type `[i32]`.
2. On that type, you call [`iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) which returns a type `Iter<_, _>` which is the iterator type for slices.
3. Now the`&`: you borrow this `Iter<_, _>` thing, resulting in `&Iter<_, _>`.

And hey, this matches the error message! Look at the last note:

```
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::IntoIterator` for `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>`
```

So... what does satisfy the `IntoIterator` trait? For one, every type that implements `Iterator` (e.g. `Iter<_, _>`) also implements `IntoIterator`. So you can just remove the `&` in the expression and it works!

But we can do even better! `IntoIterator` is also implemented for `&[T]`, so you can also just remove the `.iter()` and it works!

### Working Code

```
let s: i32 = a[1..].iter()
    .zip(&b[1..])
    .map(|(x, y)| x * y)
    .sum();
```

*Note*: I also removed the ranges' upper bounds to make them half open, [as Paolo Falabella suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061872/2408867).

Answer (score 5):

Your first version has an issue with operator precedence: `&a[1..a.len()].iter()` applies `iter()` first and then takes a reference to it, ending with a reference to a `std::slice::Iter`.

As you can see on the [docs for `Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) , there is an `impl Iterator` for `Iter` but not for `&Iter`.
This is what the first error is trying to say: (look at the part that says: `&std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>` is not an iterator).

Simplifying a bit, you can have:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    // let b = a.clone(); // no more need to clone. We're going to only
                          // work with references

    let s: i32 = (&a[1..]).iter() // you don't need the a.len() 
                                  // to slice to the end
        .zip(&a[1..])             // &a implements IntoIter, which zip 
                                  // accepts, so you don't need iter() 
        .map(|(x, y)| x * y)
        .sum();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Iterator::zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) expects something that implements `IntoIterator`.

Instead of passing an `Iterator`, you're passing a *reference* to the `Iterator`. `Iterator`s mutate, and a reference isn't sufficient.

You can resolve this by using parenthesis to make it clear what you're trying to grab a reference from

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    let b = a.clone();

    let s: i32 = (&a)[1..a.len()].iter()
        .zip(((&b)[1..b.len()]).iter())
        .map(|(x, y)| x * y)
        .sum();

    println!("{}", s);
}
```